# SQL query select TAX_ID

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables:

- the first `table1` has `fiscal_code` with some "0" filler at the begin or at the end of my `fiscal_code`
- the other `table2` has `fiscal_codes` without 0 padding

I want to find all the fiscal codes which are equal but I'd like to find which are the `fiscal_code` that has the 0 fillers and don't.

For example: if I have in the first `table1` a `fiscal_code` like `0012345, 123450` and for the other `table2` I have `fiscal_code` like `12345`, how can I extract `fiscal_code` from `table2`?

Answer (score 1):

To remove leading and trailing zeroes, use `TRIM`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table1 t1
       INNER JOIN table2 t2
       ON (TRIM(BOTH '0' FROM t1.fiscal_code) = t2.fiscal_code)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 (fiscal_code) AS
SELECT   '12345' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0012345' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0123450' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT     '123' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0000123' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT    '1230' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT     '345' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table2 (fiscal_code) AS
SELECT   '12345' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT     '123' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT     '345' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| FISCAL_CODE | FISCAL_CODE |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | 12345 |
| 0012345 | 12345 |
| 0123450 | 12345 |
| 123 | 123 |
| 0000123 | 123 |
| 1230 | 123 |
| 345 | 345 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/h9ugt0gt)

Comment: OK, but in my case i Have in the table1 for the same fiscal_code lenght 10 and 11 and in the table2 I have only fiscal_code with lenght 10. If i make a query like table1.fiscal_code = t2.fiscal_code and it gives me for example 100 record with lenght 10, i wanto to check also if for that fiscal_code exists in table1 with also lenght 11. (with 0 filler at the beginning or at the end)

Comment: @Mariomaxi This answer does exactly that it allows you to match on both length 10 and length 11 with a leading `0`. You can see that in the example where `12345` matches both `12345` and `0012345`. If you want to remove leading and trailing zeroes then use `TRIM(BOTH '0' FROM t1.fiscal_code)` instead of `LTRIM`.

Comment: ok, but in my case fiscal_code are varchar2. What can I use instead TO_NUMBER?

Comment: @Mariomaxi So are mine in the table I use for sample data. Use `TRIM` as stated in the answer.

Comment: great, now it works. Thank you so much. Another question. In this case, how can I do to  to count how many fiscal_code in table1 which has both 10 and 11  are equals to table2 which has 10 charcters?. For Example looking your output, for fiscal_code like 12345 i want a count 3, for 123 count 3 and for 345 count 1..

Comment: @Mariomaxi `GROUP BY t2.fiscal_code` and `COUNT(t1.fiscal_code)`

Comment: Thank you so much. The last one: Now I want to extract ONLY fiscal_code with 0 filler which are equals between table1 and table2. For Example, looking your output, i want to extract only value with 001234, 01234 and so on.. and which are NOT present in table2. So, i want to extract only  001234, 01234 which is presente in table1  but in table 2 must be present 1234

Comment: @Mariomaxi Find when they match without leading and trailing zeroes but do not exactly match `ON (TRIM(BOTH '0' FROM t1.fiscal_code) = t2.fiscal_code AND t1.fiscal_code != t2.fiscal_code)`